# Google+ following

Tags: google-plus

How do I know if or when I was following a person on Google+?

Does Google have history on it?

Would Google+ send me email notifications suggesting to follow someone, if I was already following them?

Legal situation.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know if or when I was following a person on Google+?

All you can see is whether you currently have them Circled, or not. (Or blocked, etc.) There's nothing in the interface showing any dates.

> Does Google have history on it?

Almost certainly.

> Would Google+ send me email notifications suggesting to follow someone, if I was already following them?

Probably not. It depends on how smart their algorithm is.

> Legal situation, thank you.

Consult an attorney. We're in no way affiliated with Google and couldn't possibly definitively provide any information on what Google does. We're just a bunch of enthusiasts helping people who have problems with Web applications.